# Lexiographically first fixed size substring for each sliding window position

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, substring, sliding-window

From given string, I want to find substring (some fixed size k) that comes first in lexiographical sort order among all substrings of same size in the string.

I would do this with sliding window over very long string (size m), and would like to find that substring for every sliding window (size n > k) position when I move it trough the string.

It seems that trivial solution would take m*O(n log(n)) time.

I think I could get to m*O(log(n)) if I make normal sort at the beginning and then just remove the substring that starts at the beginning of last window position and insert new substring that ends at the end of the current window position into already sorted collection of substrings every time I move the window. (of course I don't store substrings separetly but just keep their positions in the collection, so space requirement would be just n-k integers),

Is there faster algorithm for this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the k-long string which has a lower/higher lexicographic order. It is if you have this string "czabyrercdaresfgac" and k=3 you want to get "aby", true? A couple of example sometimes helps ;)

Comment: Yes. You are correct. and with sliding window of size n=10. aby would be answer until position 11 when "aby" would change into "are".

Answer (score 0):

Let m be the size of the input string and n be the length of the string that you're looking for. I think you can solve this in time O(m) by using suffix trees.

Start by building a suffix tree for the input string. This takes time O(m). Now, do a depth-first search on the tree, always choosing the lexicographically first choice at each step. In the course of doing so, the first string of length n that you find is the lexicographically-first substring of length n. Doing a DFS over a suffix tree for a string of length m takes time O(m), so overall this takes time O(m).